# Pyhon: Exception Value: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have set in my django project I have set the following class:

**models.py**

```
class Budget_Vendite(models.Model):
    MY_CHOICES = (
        ('jan', 'jan'),
        ('feb', 'feb'),
        ('mar', 'mar'),
        ('apr', 'apr'),
    )
    month = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=MY_CHOICES, default="")
    year=models.IntegerField(default="")
    prodotto=models.ForeignKey()
    sottoprodotto=models.ForeignKey()
    prezzo_unitario=models.DecimalField()
    quantita=models.DecimalField()
```

In my views I have set the following code:

**Views.py**

```
defaults = list(0 for m in range(12))
for prodotto_id, year, month, totale in(Budget_Vendite.objects.values_list('prodotto__name', 'year', 'month').annotate(totale=ExpressionWrapper(Sum(F('quantita') * F('prezzo_unitario')),
        output_field=FloatField())).values_list('prodotto__name', 'year', 'month', 'totale')):
        if prodotto_id not in ricavi_bdgt_2.keys():
            ricavi_bdgt_2[prodotto_id]=list(defaults)
        index=month-1
        ricavi_bdgt_2[prodotto_id][index]=totale

    total_ricavi_2={'Fatturato Previsionale': [sum(t) for t in zip(*ricavi_bdgt_2.values())]}
```

---

But django give me the following error:

```
 File "C:\Users\Federico\Desktop\Prova test\Budgeting\budget_vendite\func.py", line 36, in ce_func_bdgt

index=month-1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
```

Where is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement `index=month-1` is the cause of this error. The variable `month` is of type string, hence you have to cast it into an interger or other number type before you can do arithmetic operation on it.

In your piece of code, you need to get the index of the `month` value in `MY_CHOICES` list

```py
index=MY_CHOICES.index(month)
```

would solve the issue